# All webpages returning same data when scraping using BS4 and Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm running a very simple scrap script using BS4 and request, to get all url related to item for later to scrap all the items info.

Here is my code.

```
def all_URLs():
    list_urls = []
    url = ["https://www.masrefacciones.mx/tren-motriz/clutch-o-embrague/kit-de-clutch/valeo?PS=50&utmi_p=_tienda-oficial-valeo&utmi_pc=Banner%3acategoria11&utmi_cp=11",
           "https://www.masrefacciones.mx/tren-motriz/clutch-o-embrague/kit-de-clutch/valeo?PS=50&utmi_p=_tienda-oficial-valeo&utmi_pc=Banner%3acategoria11&utmi_cp=11#2"]

    with requests.Session() as s: # ADDED
        headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 YaBrowser/19.6.1.153 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36",
                    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                    'Referer': 'https://www.gismeteo.ru/weather-orenburg-5159/now/',
                    'DNT': '1',
                    'Connection': 'false',
                    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
                    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, max-age=0',
                    'TE': 'Trailers'} # ADDED
        for single_url in url:
            print(single_url)
            #try except to move on if any url is broken
            try:
                page = s.get(single_url,headers=headers)
                # Consider any status other than 2xx an error
                if not page.status_code // 100 == 2:
                    return "Error: Unexpected response {}".format(page)

            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                # A serious problem happened, like an SSLError or InvalidURL
                return "Error: {}".format(e)

            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")


            find_url = soup.find_all('a', class_='shelf-qd-v1-highlight', href=True)

            for url in find_url:
                #print(url)
                list_urls.append(url['href'])
            sleep(5)  # ADDED

    return list_urls

if __name__ == '__main__':

    all_urls = all_URLs()
    #get all  unique entries from the list
    set_of_urls = set(all_urls)
    print("X_X_X_X_X_X_X_")
    #print("list ",len(all_urls),"set ",len(set_of_urls))
    for a in set_of_urls:
        print(a)
```

each page have 50 products, after I run the above script  I've got 100 prducts on the list, but only 50 unique product. It Does not matter the pagination I use, I always get two times the data from the first page.

I've tried many solutions found here as to use requests.Session(), change headers, add a timeout between requests. None of them change the output.

Just a remark about the output, the HTML class I used have 3 href, that is the reason we have 300 item in the list, 150 from the first link plus 150 from the second one. But I have only 50 items in the set, all of them from the first link.
Here is the output:

https://www.masrefacciones.mx/tren-motriz/clutch-o-embrague/kit-de-clutch/valeo?PS=50&utmi_p=_tienda-oficial-valeo&utmi_pc=Banner%3acategoria11&utmi_cp=11
https://www.masrefacciones.mx/tren-motriz/clutch-o-embrague/kit-de-clutch/valeo?PS=50&utmi_p=_tienda-oficial-valeo&utmi_pc=Banner%3acategoria11&utmi_cp=11#2

X_X_X_X_X_X_X_

list  300 set  50

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: The code seems to work, when I open both urls in browser, they looks the same

Comment: If you check carefully the items, you're going to see the list is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pagination is dinamically changed by JS. Clicking inspect on my browser and checking the Network tab, I could figure out how the real pagination is generated by JS and solved my problem.

Below is the real url used for the pagination.

```
https://www.masrefacciones.mx/buscapagina?fq=C%3a%2f17%2f1705%2f170502%2f&fq=B%3a1931&PS=10&sl=53129450-e8c5-47ac-a87c-d2565d825bce&cc=1&sm=0&PageNumber=2
```

Follow a picture of how to find the pagination:
[image]